# Find count of item that occurs in multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assuming a table

```
source_document_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
target_document_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
similarity DOUBLE NOT NULL,
```

If I wanted to determine the frequency of occurrence of a documents in the source_document_id column, my query would run something like this:

```
select count(source_document_id) as c1, source_document_id from PROJECT_0622.SIMILARITY_RESULT group by source_document_id order by  c1 desc;
```

But considering the fact tha a document Id can occur in either the source_document_id or target_document_id column, ... 
how would I find the frequency of documentIds occurring in either column?

For example, 
consider data thus

```
source_document_id source_document_id similarity
1 2 0.8
1 3 0.8
1 4 0.7
4 5 0.8
4 8 0.75
9 4 0.9      
2 4 0.99
```

I would like to achieve results something like this

```
frequency in source/target doc id column, doc_id
5 4
3 1
2 2    
1 8    
1 3
1 9
1 10
```

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: All good answers that address my question. Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance that aggregating the data twice will have better performance:

```
select id, sum(cnt) as n_docs
from ((select source_document_id as id, count(*) as cnt
       from similarity
       group by source_document_id
      ) union all
      (select target_document_id as id
       from similarity
       group by target_document_id
      )
     ) t
group by id;
```

If performance is a consideration, it is worth trying both methods, particularly if there is are indexes on the two columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge your two columns into a single column using a `union all`, then perform your count on this aggregate column:

```
select doc_id, count(*) n_docs
from
(
select source_document_id as doc_id from similarity
union all
select target_document_id as doc_id from similarity
)
group by doc_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting both `source_document_id` and `target_document_id` in one column using `union`. Then simply `group by`.

[The following query works in SQL Server, maybe you need to make some small changes to make it work in postgresql]

```
select id, count(*)
from
(
    select source_document_id as id
    from PROJECT_0622.SIMILARITY_RESULT
    union all
    select target_document_id as id
    from PROJECT_0622.SIMILARITY_RESULT
) ids
group by id
```